# I want to re-structure my website to Laravel, but i don't want to lose Google authorship for the old URLs

Tags: laravel, web

I want to re-structure my website to Laravel, but I don't want to lose google authorship for the old URLs.

What can I do to keep the authority while the old URLs will be changed totally.

Answer (score 0):

If your current site is not using "friendly urls" like laravel does, so could be a slow process and you need to do some manuel redirections in your server/project.

Google takes into account the [301 redirection](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=es) to change a url and transfeer all the properties, PR; autorship, relevance, etc.

So basically you need to specifically "say" to your server to redirect, for example: www.yoursite.com/page.html to www.yoursite.com/page/ using 301 redirections.

Hope it helps.